# multiple Cross-Origin request

Tags: javascript

A page with origin A wants to perform a GET request to a page with origin B. And the page with origin want to perform a GET request to a page with origin C. I want  result from C to B and B to A in callback functions.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Enable CORS for all of them.

Comment: where should i enble CROS in asp .net. if possible any sample code

Comment: www.google.com would be a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

```
In web.config, add the following.

<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: No its not working..  if i use single callback method i am getting result. But i want result in chain process. The request from A to B then from request from B to C. Once i got result in C, it should come to B in callback event and B to A in callback event.